# I want to create custom action bar like copy, paste which will work for all apps for selection of word in android

Tags: android

Whenever we long press on words ,it gets selected and the option appears to copy/paste. I want to add an extra custom button which will select the word and will open my app. I use

```
 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 editText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback()
```

but it is limited only to that editText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported and hopefully is not possible outside of rooted devices. You cannot hack into the GUIs of other applications to affect how they handle these sorts of events.

Comment: @Selvin: That will only affect those apps that happen to be using `ShareActionProvider` when "we long press on words". While some apps will do that, I do not find it to be especially common.