# Custom cut/copy action menu for long press on text in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an app where I want to be able to show a `TextView` 
that allows the user to select some text if a user selected some text need to display custom menu. Example: custom search and Google search... .

I can intercept long-press to show my own action menu like. Reference text::: An `ActionBar` is located at the top of an activity and it can display any number of status or navigation related elements such as title, icon, buttons, or arbitrary action-related views.

If I select text "An ActionBar is located at" Then I need a menu like that text need to search in Google search or Wikipedia search.

Need code for this requirement.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997414/i-want-to-create-custom-action-bar-like-copy-paste-which-will-work-for-all-apps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386084/how-do-i-enable-standard-copy-paste-for-a-textview-in-android